# 'Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)'の解決方法

Tags: mysql, sql

explain で
'Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)'
というのがでて INDEX を使ってくれません

https://nishinatoshiharu.com/overview-nested-loopjoin/
検索するとこういう記事が出てきてINDEXをつけると治るとかいてあるんですが元からついています

---

該当のクエリ

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
  user_id, target_id, u.x, u.y 
FROM targets t
JOIN user_positions u USING(user_id)
WHERE state = 0
AND u.x IS NOT NULL
AND (u.x - t.x) * (u.x - t.x) + (u.y - t.y) * (u.y - t.y) < 1.0

+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  52245 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 680924 |     9.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

targets はデバッグようにテーブルにしてますが
実際はサブクエリなのでインデックスはつけられません
調べるべき user_id と座標情報を持っています

```
CREATE TABLE `targets` (
  `user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `target_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `x` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `y` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

user_positions は user_id ごとに座標と状態情報を持ったテーブルで
user_id にユニークインデックスを貼っています

```
CREATE TABLE `user_positions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `x` decimal(9,6) NOT NULL,
  `y` decimal(9,6) NOT NULL,
  `state` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_user_positions_on_user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

サブクエリで計算された targets が 4 万件程度で
user_positions は 100万件ほどレコードがあります

`join user_positions USING(user_id)`　
ブログでいうところの targets が駆動テーブル user_positions が内部テーブルで
で INDEX のついた user_id で join しているので INDEX がきくはずなんで
4万件程度の距離計算なら一瞬で終わるかなと思ったんですが
なぜかこれが数分経っても終わりません

実行計画を見たところ
`Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)`
というのがあってインデックスが使われていませんでした

どうすれば解決できるのでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CHARSET` が異なるため index を利用できていないように見えます。

例えば [`convert()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/charset-convert.html) で `targets.user_id` を `latin1` に変換すると index が利用されました。

```sql
SELECT 
  t.user_id, target_id, u.x, u.y 
FROM targets t
JOIN user_positions u on convert(t.user_id using latin1) = u.user_id
WHERE state = 0
AND u.x IS NOT NULL
AND (u.x - t.x) * (u.x - t.x) + (u.y - t.y) * (u.y - t.y) < 1.0
;
```

比較: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ca174/9

Comment: その通りでした。ありがとうございます。助かりました